# How to find unused structure definitions in C automatically?

Tags: c, gcc

GCC will warn on unused functions, labels, etc. But it seems it doesn't warn on unused definitions? Is there a way to detect unused struct definitions automatically?

Comment: I don't think you want to be warned about any unused struct definition in various library headers. And in order to perform such check only in your files you can write a simple python script...

Comment: GCC will warn on unused **static** functions. It will not warn on unused global functions because that would (1) require global program analysis and (2) make using libraries impossible. You almost never use *all* functions from any given library. Types are global so the same reasoning applies to them.

Comment: Looking for unused structs is a minefield.  First you have to define what used means.  If the struct appears in a typedef or a union or another struct, is that a use  if that typedef, union or struct is never used.  How about nameless structs?

Comment: Really? GCC warns on unused labels? I never tried but I'd assume it only does so if the statements after the label are not reached by another way, and the diagnostic will be "dead code".

Comment: @AlexLop. I doubt that script to be "simple". It will rapidly approach a C parser. Are you thinking of a specific library or module which would make implementing such a script easy?

Comment: @Yunnosch I agree that it may be not that simple when implementing it for any possible C syntax writing. But assuming specific coding convention for personal usage shouldn’t be too complicated

Comment: @AlexLop. "Should not be" but is. I tried (admittedly in a different language than python, that is why I ask about a lib you have in mind). And with some pretty tight coding rules in place which should have made the input code predictable via some assumptions....

Answer (score 3):

You won't necessarily be able to identify individual structs but there is a tool called `include-what-you-use` which allows you to eliminate unused includes.  See here:
https://include-what-you-use.org/

and here for using with CMake:
[How to use the tool include-what-you-use together with CMake to detect unused headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30951492/how-to-use-the-tool-include-what-you-use-together-with-cmake-to-detect-unused-he)