# Using IWYU fix_includes.py with CMake - more friendly instuctions

Tags: cmake, iwyu, include-what-you-use

I have problem running tool fix_includes.py that automatically fixes up source files based on the include-what-you-use recommendations.

I have configured IWYU tool accordingly to the documentation:

- downloaded IWYU version matching my Clang version
- located it following the [issue 100](https://github.com/include-what-you-use/include-what-you-use/issues/100) So IWYU is located in `/usr/bin/iwyu/include-what-you-use` and clang in
  `/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0`
- in `/usr/bin/iwyu/` built it with following commands:

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/lib/llvm 10/lib/clang/10.0.0
make
sudo make install
```

- set CXX_INCLUDE_WHAT_YOU_USE property in CMakefile.txt in my project root `/home/kpolok/worksapce/projects/using_iwyu_proj`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.3)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
project(using_mocks_with_di_proj LANGUAGES CXX)

option(USE_IWYU "Enable include-what-you-use reports during build" ON)

if(USE_IWYU)
    find_program(IWYU_PATH NAMES include-what-you-use iwyu)
    if(NOT IWYU_PATH)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find the program include-what-you-use")
    endif()
    message("Found IWYU ${IWYU_PATH}")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_INCLUDE_WHAT_YOU_USE ${IWYU_PATH})
    set(CMAKE_CXX_INCLUDE_WHAT_YOU_USE ${IWYU_PATH})
endif()

set(PROJ_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})

add_subdirectory(app)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

And it produces report while building:

```
[ 20%] Building CXX object src/Car/CMakeFiles/Car.dir/src/Car.cpp.o
Warning: include-what-you-use reported diagnostics:

/home/kpolok/worksapce/projects/using_iwyu_proj/src/Car/inc/Car.h should add these lines:
class MotorIf;

/home/kpolok/worksapce/projects/using_iwyu_proj/src/Car/inc/Car.h should remove these lines:
- #include "MotorIf.h"  // lines 2-2

The full include-list for /home/kpolok/worksapce/projects/using_iwyu_proj/src/Car/inc/Car.h:
class MotorIf;
---

/home/kpolok/worksapce/projects/using_iwyu_proj/src/Car/src/Car.cpp should add these lines:
#include "inc/MotorIf.h"  // for MotorIf

/home/kpolok/worksapce/projects/using_iwyu_proj/src/Car/src/Car.cpp should remove these lines:

The full include-list for /home/kpolok/worksapce/projects/using_iwyu_proj/src/Car/src/Car.cpp:
#include "inc/Car.h"
#include <iostream>       // for basic_ostream::operator<<, operator<<, endl
#include "inc/MotorIf.h"  // for MotorIf
---

[ 40%] Building CXX object src/Car/CMakeFiles/Car.dir/src/CarMotor.cpp.o
[ 60%] Linking CXX static library libCar.a
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/kpolok/worksapce/projects/using_iwyu_proj/build'
[ 60%] Built target Car
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/kpolok/worksapce/projects/using_iwyu_proj/build'
Scanning dependencies of target Executable
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/kpolok/worksapce/projects/using_iwyu_proj/build'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/kpolok/worksapce/projects/using_iwyu_proj/build'
[ 80%] Building CXX object app/CMakeFiles/Executable.dir/main.cpp.o
Warning: include-what-you-use reported diagnostics:

/home/kpolok/worksapce/projects/using_iwyu_proj/app/main.cpp should add these lines:

/home/kpolok/worksapce/projects/using_iwyu_proj/app/main.cpp should remove these lines:
- #include <vector>  // lines 2-2

The full include-list for /home/kpolok/worksapce/projects/using_iwyu_proj/app/main.cpp:
#include <iostream>        // for operator<<, endl, basic_ostream, cout, ost...
#include "inc/Car.h"       // for Car
#include "inc/CarMotor.h"  // for CarMotor
```

That part went pretty smooth, but now i want to use the script fix_includes.py. So I once more followed the documentation and invoked this commands in my project root `/home/kpolok/worksapce/projects/using_iwyu_proj`:

```
make -k CXX=/usr/bin/iwyu/build/bin/include-what-you-use CXXFLAGS="-Xiwyu --error_always" 2> ./err.txt
python3 /usr/bin/iwyu/include-what-you-use/fix_includes.py < ./err.txt
```

But after first command I get:

```
rm -rf build
mkdir build
cmake -S . -B ./build/
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/iwyu/build/bin/include-what-you-use
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/iwyu/build/bin/include-what-you-use -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:53 (message):
  The C++ compiler

    "/usr/bin/iwyu/build/bin/include-what-you-use"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /home/kpolok/worksapce/projects/using_iwyu_proj/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_d324c/fast && make[1]: Entering directory '/home/kpolok/worksapce/projects/using_iwyu_proj/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_d324c.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_d324c.dir/build
    make[2]: Entering directory '/home/kpolok/worksapce/projects/using_iwyu_proj/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_d324c.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
...
 CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
 CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)
```

By the way, the Makefile in my project root  looks like this:

```
all: prepare configure build_project

prepare:
    rm -rf build
    mkdir build

configure:
    cmake -S . -B ./build/

build_project:
    cmake --build ./build/
```

I'm quite new to cmake/clang stuff so I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I suppose that those commands should be invoked somewhere else?But exactly where? Maybe something else is off?

Btw IMO the instructions I found in IWYU documentations aren't really clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Friedrich mentioned, I was confusing make with cmake (in fact, I was blindly following the IWYU documentation, without trying to understand, what I was actually doing). The solution to the problem is easy.
So, during the build process, CMake already generates the report required by the *fix_includes.py* script by utilizing the CMAKE_CXX_INCLUDE_WHAT_YOU_USE variable.

```
option(USE_IWYU "Enable include-what-you-use reports during build" ON)

if(USE_IWYU)
    find_program(IWYU_PATH NAMES include-what-you-use iwyu)
    if(NOT IWYU_PATH)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find the program include-what-you-use")
    endif()
    message("Found IWYU ${IWYU_PATH}")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_INCLUDE_WHAT_YOU_USE ${IWYU_PATH})
endif()
```

I just needed to separate IWYU report from the build logs part:

```
if(USE_IWYU)
    find_program(IWYU_PATH NAMES include-what-you-use iwyu)
    if(NOT IWYU_PATH)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find the program include-what-you-use")
    endif()
    message("Found IWYU ${IWYU_PATH}")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_INCLUDE_WHAT_YOU_USE ${IWYU_PATH} CXXFLAGS="-Xiwyu --error_always")
endif()
```

Thanks to *--error_always*, IWYU report parts are treated as errors.
Now I need to collect this report e.g. by redirecting it to separate file:

```
build_project:
    cmake --build ./build/ 2> report.txt
```

This is the part of my Makefile that triggers cmake build process.
All that's left is to run the *fix_includes.py*:

```
using_iwyu_proj$ python3 /usr/bin/iwyu/include-what-you-use/fix_includes.py < report.txt
>>> Fixing #includes in '/home/kpolok/worksapce/projects/using_iwyu_proj/src/Car/inc/Car.h'
>>> Fixing #includes in '/home/kpolok/worksapce/projects/using_iwyu_proj/src/Car/src/Car.cpp'
>>> Fixing #includes in '/home/kpolok/worksapce/projects/using_iwyu_proj/app/main.cpp'
IWYU edited 3 files on your behalf.
```

Comment: Glad you were able to figure something out. I was afraid other (compiler) errors might trip up `fix_includes.py`. If it works like this, you might even make the fix step part of your makefile.

Answer (score 1):

I can explain why it's not working but unfortunately I wasn't able to find how to run `fix_includes.py` from CMake.

There's something peculiar about your project: you're using Make to call CMake. CMake will in turn generate a makefile and call Make to build the project (`cmake --build` does this under the hood). Having a makefile to call CMake is uncommon but not inherently wrong.

When using CMake, projects usually decide to only have a `CMakeLists.txt` in their root dir and generate makefiles with `cmake -S <project_root> -B <some_build_dir>`.

The instructions you refer to are - I think - [iwyu's readme](https://github.com/include-what-you-use/include-what-you-use).
The guidelines for use with Make and CMake found there are **mutually exclusive**. Take a look in your build directory, there's another `Makefile` there and it looks nothing like yours. If anything, you would have to call `make CXX=iwyu 2> err` there but that will not work either. This is owed to how CMake generated makefiles look. There's just no variable `CXX` in there to override.

Replacing the compiler with `iwyu` before running CMake will not work either, as you found out. CMake will try to compile some test programs to gauge your compiler's capabilities and `iwyu` just doesn't compile anything. So CMake considers this "compiler" to be broken and refuses to go on.

The correct way to use iwyu from CMake is to set a special CMake variable `CMAKE_CXX_INCLUDE_WHAT_YOU_USE` either from command line when configuring with CMake:

```
cmake "-DCMAKE_CXX_INCLUDE_WHAT_YOU_USE=/usr/bin/iwyu" -S . -B build
```

or from `CMakeLists.txt` as you already do (twice, btw). You also observed this to work.

So you will either have to give up on using CMake and write a plain old makefile (containing a variable `CXX`) or find a way to massage CMake's output into something that can be fed into `fix_includes.py`.

As I initially wrote, I don't have a solution for you. Maybe you can figure something out on your own. I'm hoping a more proficient user will write a better answer.

To get you started, [CMake is actually very well documented](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/). For using static code checkers (iwyu and others), I find [this blog post](https://www.kitware.com/static-checks-with-cmake-cdash-iwyu-clang-tidy-lwyu-cpplint-and-cppcheck/) helpful. And there's also the question [How can I use the tool 'Include What You Use' together with CMake to detect unused headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30951492/how-can-i-use-the-tool-include-what-you-use-together-with-cmake-to-detect-unus) None of them explain how to run `fix_includes.py` from CMake, unfortunately.